# How bacnet device reply Iam message

Tags: java, build-automation, bacnet4j

I been trying to understand how bacnet java works on device reply “iam” message to the respective call

For example:
1.  Device 5678 send broadcast message with new whois message(device id 1234)
2.  Device 1234 replies “iam” message to device 5678.

Questions 
How device 1234 send “iam” message to 5678?
Which part of JAVA code does that??

I'm happy for any input on the subject.

Best regards
Sorc

Answer (score 1):

who-is and i-am are both unconfirmed BACnet services.
when a who-is is sent (broadcast or unicast) by a device, other devices present in network reply with i-am.

assuming that you are using java based BACnet stack (library) to create your own application. your application will receive i-am, that received from network in the form of callback from stack library.

in general the stack (implemented in any programming language) will decode this data and pass it to application in the form of callbacks.

hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

On the basis that the Who-Is broadcast contains the SADR/source address, the receiving devices knows where to send it's response - if it did want to give a unicast/directed response.

You then have to listen out for the UDP (- UDP/IP -) response, and then you have to parse it, for the Object ID.